# NVidia 840M: Is it running on Power Saving mode?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I was trying to monitor the performance of my NVidia 840M 2GB in-game. Following are the stats:

```
GPU Temperature: 59C to 63C (Maximum)
GPU Usage: 99% (Hovers between 94%-99%)
GPU Core Clock: 540MHz (Locked)
GPU Memory Usage: 900 MHz, 704MB
(Extra information: FPS in Assassin's Creed Black Flag: 40-45FPS
Stats measured using MSIAfterburner)
```

However, the specs of my card are:

```
GPU Core Speed: 1024MHz (+Boost)
GPU Memory: 2000MHz (effective)
```

My question is, are these values during in-game normal or my NVidia 840M is running at power saving mode or under-performing?

Comment: when in game, is the laptop at all hot?

Comment: [NotebookCheck mention](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-840M.105681.0.html) AC:BF in 40-45 FPS as good enough for 840M. Can you try measuring it in GPU-Z?

Comment: No, the laptop doesn't get hot at all. And GPU-Z tells me the same readings.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "Manage 3D settings" in Nvidia control panel, where you can change the power management mode globally or specifically for one program.

Comment: Yes, I did that but that did not help too.